# failed to load external entity "https://ws.hipay.com/soap/payment-v2?wsdl"

Tags: laravel, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm using a hipay account and used there webservices to integrate in my website laravel.

i used the same code sharing in other project and its works fine but now in other projet it generate an error in the begining of file Saop

SoapFault
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://ws.hipay.com/soap/payment-v2?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://ws.hipay.com/soap/payment-v2?wsdl"

and there is my code

```
    `$options = array(
    'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8'
    );

    $client = new SoapClient('https://ws.hipay.com/soap/payment-v2?wsdl', 
    $options);`
```

i used an OVH hosted , Thank you

Answer (score 0):

test this code :

```
<?php

$opts = array(
'http' => array(
    'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
)
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$options = [
'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP,
'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
'stream_context' => $context,
];

$client = new SoapClient('https://ws.hipay.com/soap/payment-v2?wsdl',$options);
```

Comment: Thank you  so much i just found the solution its about to change in .ovhConfig file in the root  -> change container.image=legacy to container.image=stable .